# Custom Firebase Authentication with Username and Password

Tags: android, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an Android app, where the authentication needs to be performed with `username` and `password` (on the **logIn** part) and `email`, `password` and `username` (on the **Register** part). The username and the email need to be unique.

I've followed this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) where *Firebase* tells us how to sign in user with custom token, generated by our own backend(in my case *Spring Boot*), but this is only for signing in.

**How the registration part needs to be handled?**

When the user registers, I need to check and save the data from the backend into Firebase, return the token and sign in with this token, or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a custom authentication provider to sign in to Firebase, it's your own provider that handles the registration of the users. Firebase Authentication in this scenario doesn't maintain any information for the user.

So you will need to store your own database of user names, (hashed) passwords, and other data that you maintain. You can of course use one of Firebase's databases (Firestore or Realtime Database) for that purpose, but Firebase Authentication will not know of that.

For an example of a username + password provider, see this repo: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth

---

As a different approach you could also use the existing email+password provider of Firebase, and add a user name requirement on top of that. Here too you'd store the user name in an external database, as Firebase Authentication won't know anything about it.

This is a more common approach, and you can find out a lot more about what folks have done there by looking at [questions around storing a unique user name](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+unique+username).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I've though - that for the registration I need to store them in the database (Firestore, Realtime DB), provide the JWT back and then just call ```signInWithCustomToken();```. But after that I can limit the access to the user's credentials i.e. giving access to this part in the DB only to my backend, right?

Comment: Yup. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules for full details, but basically if you disallow reads/writes to your database, only callers with elevated permissions (such as those using the Admin SDK) can access the data.

Comment: Ahh okay. So basically we can't set rules for a specific node? e.g. ```user's registration: read - false, write - false;``` and  ```user's projects: read - only auth, write - only auth```

Comment: You can definitely set access rules on specific node, but its a bit hard to judge what's going on there from your comments. If you're having trouble with that, I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal rules + code that reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've created the custom token on my server. Now when I use ```signInWithCustomToken()``` how to be sure that when the user if authenticated even if he closes the app and comes back after one hour, he won't be needed to login again? (Like Facebook's behaviour, we log in only when we have signed in)